# Can I use Firebase Dynamic Link as URL shortener?

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Can I use Firebase Dynamic Links as URL shortener for a web application? Will it work even if I have no iOS or Android app? If that is the case, what's the use of dynamicLinkDomain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Firebase Dynamic Links as URL Shortener.

When creating link specify your deep link. When user taps on the short dynamic link, navigation will happens to deep link. This enough to make link work.

dynamicLinkDomain is domain assigned to your Firebase project. All your Firebase Dynamic links will be hosted on this domain.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a follow up question though, where can I find the dynamicLinkDomain for my app engine? BTW, I'm sorting things out so I still don't have Firebase project.

Comment: When you create the Firebase project, and in the project enable Dynamic Links, you will see your domain. You can also contact Firebase support to assign customized domain.